# node.js readFile txt add question mark at top of content

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am getting some datas from .txt with `fs.readFile()` function but top of the content is like "?Alex libman"

My whole code ;

```
fs.readFile(__dirname+"/txts/generate/titles0.txt", "utf-8", function (ex, titles) {
var titlesArr =  titles.split("\r\n");
console.log(titlesArr);
});
```

Result;

```
["?Alex libman","Kroya Barzo","Deliah Krbo"]
```

Always , there is question mark at top of content

Note:my titles0.txt is line by line data

Comment: So you probably have a questionmark in your file then ?

Comment: edited , no there is no question mark in txt file , i controlled , this issue comes to me second time , if i give an empty line at tap of txt , there is no prob. What can i do ?

Comment: maybe it is about utf8 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert your file to UTF-8 without [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You can do that by using this command in your terminal:

```
tail --bytes=+4 utf8_with_bom.txt > utf8_without_bom.txt
```

Or you may remove BOM with the help of text editors like Sublime Text (`File -> Save with Encoding -> UTF-8`) or Notepad++ (`Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`).

Comment: Yea , Thats true , i used notepad++ to save txt file UTF-8 without BOM, thank you so much